# Can I write a coordinated two-device test on Android

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am writing a messenger app in Android and I want to test this application across two devices. The kind of test I would like to do is the following:

1. Phone 1 creates a new chat room
2. Phone 2 joins that chat room

   ---> Test that Phone 1 sees a new person in the chat room.

It seems pointless to try and test this on a single phone. What I need is coordination between tests running on two separate devices at the same time. Is this possible?

For my current testing I am using Espresso, so something similar would be ideal, but I will consider using any testing suite.